# How recursion is returning values in the code

Tags: python

I am having difficulties understanding recursion. I am having basic understanding of recursion where it follows stack concepts but got stuck at a below program explanation

I read code for reversing a string using recursion. Code I have seen is

```
a = "nitesh"
def abc(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return a
    return abc(a[1:]) + a[0]    

print(abc(a))
```

Output is

```
hsetin
```

This is what I understood

--> if len(a) == 0: return  ---> This is the exit condition which is must for recursion

--> return abc[a[1:]) ---> This is where recursion is coming in picture. Here it is slicing the string starting from first index. At every iteration, it will take the next index. When length of string becomes 0, it returns ""(empty string) and then it starts returning. Next iteration will have last element (h). then how next iteration is returning `s`. I am confused

Answer (score 1):

Consider this call graph, you start at the top and each function call is one line below.  At the start the recursive function will call itself, with smaller and smaller input, but before the base case is reached it won't return any values back up.

abc("nitesh")
abc("itesh")
abc("tesh")
abc("tesh")
abc("tesh")
abc("tesh")
abc("esh")
abc("sh")
abc("h")
abc("")

Now it will start moving "back up" the calls as they start returning values, instead of calling recursively.

abc("") returns ""
abc("h") receives "" and appends "h" returning "h"
abc("sh") receives "h" and appends "s" returning "hs"
abc("esh") receives "hs" and appends "e" returning "hse"
...

working its way back up until "hsetin"

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function abc on a string of non-zero length, the function is not returning a number but only the next function call is put on top of the stack. Note that `a` is a variable **local** to the function, so it has a new definition within each function call.
Do it step by step:
a = "nitesh", so len(a) > 0 and the function returns
abc(a[1:])+a[0] = abc("itesh") + "n".
To evaluate this, the function call abc("itesh") is executed (with now a="itesh") and returns abc("tesh") + "itesh"[0] = abc("tesh") + "i", so the overall return value is by now abc("tesh") + "i" + "n". This continues until `abc` is finally called on the empty string, which returns an empty string, and the concatenation of all strings returned in the course of the recursive function calls is the reverse of the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Below '->' means returns.

```
abc('nitesh') -> abc('itesh') + 'n'
abc('itesh') -> abc('tesh') + 'i'
abc('tesh') -> abc('esh') + 't'
abc('esh') -> abc('sh') + 'e'
abc('sh') -> abc('h') + 's'
abc('h') -> abc('') + 'h'
abc('') -> ''
```

Finally it returns the blank character, now traceback

```
abc('h') -> '' + 'h'
abc('sh') -> 'h' + 's'
abc('esh') -> 'hs' + 'e'
abc('tesh') -> 'hse' + 't'
abc('itesh') -> 'hset' + 'i'
abc('nitesh') -> 'hseti' + 'n' -> 'hsetin'
```

> Just jot it down on a paper and you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this step by step. It will tell you what happend.
 http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%22nitesh%22%0Adef%20abc%28a%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20len%28a%29%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a%0A%20%20%20%20return%20abc%28a%5B1%3A%5D%29%20%2B%20a%5B0%5D%20%20%20%20%0A%0Aprint%28abc%28a%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=31&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false[image]